# WPF solution design of slideshow application

Tags: wpf, architecture

Been thinking about this for hours now. Im building a simple slideshow application, where the user creates slides through a web application and publishes them to a wpf "player". The user is allowed to create two types of slides one based on html and one based on xaml (thought this would be easy).

When i get the slide to the player i have to determine how to render/load the slide. The HTML slide i convert to xaml (code i found on msdn) as a flowdocument (but now what to do with it?). The Xaml i just get in "raw" xaml.

My plan is to convert both of these to xaml, then have the slide load the xaml in someway and display it, but how? And would this setup be the proper architecture? please bear in mind that this is a small player application.

Any help on either architecture or on how to display these are highly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Brian

Comment: What's your end goal? A single executable containing the slideshow? An XBAP they'll view in the browser? Will they just download the XAML which another application will read in and display?

Comment: The end goal is a generic player that will play any html i throw at it and in time, also will provide  touch screen functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Slide.Show](http://www.vertigo.com/SlideShow.aspx) project from Vertigo.  It a WPF project released under codeplex.  It may give you ideas on the design.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just display them in the web page? There are a huge number of slideshow applications for the web already.

Comment: I want to do something visually cool, and be able to play movies, show static text, show images, touch screens (eventually). I just feel like the html browser approach isnt sufficient (did a player that way for the prorotype)